# How to remove the Undo button in plotly dash after a dropdown update

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

After updating a dropdown box in Plotly Dash, an undo button appears down the bottom left of the screen, and doesn't go away.

How do I remove it?

Comment: See https://community.plot.ly/t/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-floating-toolbar/4911/12?u=chriddyp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**MAY 2019 UPDATE**
Starting in Dash 1.0 the Undo button is hidden by default. [#724](https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/724)
To turn the Undo/Redo button back on use: `app = dash.Dash(show_undo_redo=True)`

**AUG 2018 UPDATE**: There is currently an issue out on GitHub to add a feature into Dash to do this for you. You can check its status [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/234) to see if it has been implemented yet.

You can do this by attaching external css. You can append external css with the following code:

```
app.css.append_css({
   'external_url': (
       'link-to-your-css'
   )
})
```

In your css code you will want to have the line:

```
._dash-undo-redo {
  display: none;
}
```

for example, some of my css where I turn the undo button of is:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lwileczek/Dash@master/v5.css

if you make a css file on github you can use
https://www.jsdelivr.com/ 
to create a url to post in "append_css". If you do this, make sure your file ends with .css

currently, this link is exactly what you need, but if you have other css you'll have to create a new css file.
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lwileczek/Dash@master/v5.css

furthermore, if you don't like all the buttons added to your graphs, when you create a graph you can hide them with the following code

```
 dcc.Graph(id='my_graph',config={'displayModeBar': False})
```

I found a very similar question posted on plotly's own forum. Their lead developer responds often. Here is his response to this:
https://community.plot.ly/t/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-floating-toolbar/4911/11
Hope this helps. Let me know if there are further questions.

---

Exact code needed.

```
app.css.append_css({'external_url': ( 
    'cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lwileczek/Dash@master/v5.css'
)})
```

Comment: exact code required:
     app.css.append_css({'external_url': ( ' https://rawgit.com/lwileczek/Dash/master/undo_redo5.css')})

Comment: This link is broken now that rawgit is going away